# Programmatically export individual user PDF reports from Power BI with Power Automate

Tags: powerbi, power-automate, power-automate-desktop

I have a Power BI report displaying disk usage data with various visualizations. It includes:

- A slicer for filtering by user ID
- A table showing disk usage details per user (paths, sizes)

My goal is to automate this PDF generation process for each user in the database, creating individual reports. Is this achievable using Power Automate web (preferably not Desktop)? If so, what approach would be most efficient?

Additional details:

The data source for the Power BI report is a CSV file.